Inclusion of field extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$
Could you help me clear up a confusion? Either my following reasoning is wrong, or I should be able to show that $\omega_{2p} \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$, which does not seem correct.
Degree of Field Extensions
Let $\omega_p$ be a primitive $p$-th root of unity $\omega_p := e^{2\pi i / p}$ and $\omega_{2p}$ a primitive $2p$-th root of unity $\omega_{2p} := e^{2\pi i / (2p)}$ ($p$ an odd prime).
Let $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ be the field obtained by adjoining $\omega_p$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. The degree of this extension is $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(p) = p-1$.
Let $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$ be the field obtained by adjoining $\omega_{2p}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$. The degree of this extension is $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) : \mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(2p) = \varphi(2) \varphi(p) = 1 \cdot (p-1) = p-1$.
Inclusion of Fields
Since $\omega_p = (\omega_{2p})^2$, it follows that $\omega_p \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$.
Given the tower $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$, the multiplicativity of degrees in a tower of fields gives:
[$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$ : $\mathbb{Q}$] = [$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$ : $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$][$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ : $\mathbb{Q}$].
Since
[$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) : \mathbb{Q}$] = $p-1$
and
[$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) : \mathbb{Q}$] = $p-1$, it follows that:
[$\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) : \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$] = $\frac{[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) : \mathbb{Q}]}{[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) : \mathbb{Q}]}$ = $\frac{p-1}{p-1} = 1$.
Thus, $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) : \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)] = 1$, meaning $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p}) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$.
This implies that $\omega_{2p} \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$. In particular, that $\sqrt\omega_p \in \mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ something I cannot see how could be the case. So, there must be something wrong, which I cannot identify.

You should draw a picture.  Hint: $-(\omega_5)^3 = \omega_{10}$.  Perhaps you know that the group of units of $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_n)$ has order depending on whether $n$ is even or odd?

In other words, $\omega_p$ and $\omega_q$ generate $\omega_{pq}$ if $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime. But $\omega_2 = -1$ is already in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I remember something about the group of units $\mathbb{Z}[\omega_n]^{\times}$ being isomorphic to $g^n \times \mathbb{Z}^r$ where $g^n$ is the group of $n$-th roots of unity and r is the rank of the free abelian part, but I don't know how this could help.

I will try to think a little bit further, but just as a starting point, is my argument for $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p) = \mathbb{Q}(\omega_{2p})$ right then?

Your argument seems correct except when $p=2$, where $\varphi(2p)=2\neq p-1$.

To answer your question, based on the comments, for odd prime numbers $p$ indeed  $\omega_{2p}\in\mathbb Q(\omega_{p})$, because $$-\left(\omega_p^{\;(p+1)/2}\right)=e^{\frac{2\pi i}2}e^{\frac{2\pi i}p\frac{p+1}2}=e^{2\pi i}e^{2\pi i/(2p)}=\omega_{2p}.$$
